# Names for parts of a mug?

Tags: american-english

What are the different parts of the mug? I only know the handle.

Comment: "the rest of the mug" is the other part. :P

Comment: Joking aside, that's probably the best answer you'll get. The part of the mug that isn't the handle is just the container that liquid goes in, I don't think it has a specific name beyond "mug".

Comment: I definitely agree. I tried searching the web couldn't find one. The best that I could find was walls of a mug and mug bottom.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for specialized terminology, and not about general English grammar or usage.

Comment: Please don't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handle, the body, the lip (which is the rim of the mug), the foot (which is the base).

Comment: 'Mig' or 'mug'?

Comment: As I've never heard the rim of a fighter jet referred to as a lip, I'm guessing he meant mug. ;)

Comment: Here's a reliable resource but w/o illustrations though.  http://gotheborg.com/glossary/namesofshapes.shtml